# Can you open a hidden window?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I load an/more url(s) in a hidden window by loading a website? How can do it with javascript without redirecting the parent page? I can allow pop up windows. But as most of the browsers will block pop ups I want to load a hidden window. I want to retrieve some data from the child window. And when the parent window is closed the child window(s) also get closed. Can anyone help me out in this one?

Comment: There is no such thing "hidden window". What you are after is called AJAX - client side script send "silent" request to server (no page reload) and can read the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create iframes either in you html or programming, if you want to show them you can do it but for the security reasons the browser won't let you to access their data.